# How to convert mortran code to fortran code

Tags: fortran

I have some Mortran code (from glmnet) that I want to read and compile. I know that in compiling, Mortran is first converted to Fortran and then compiled, if one has the pre-processor. How does one install the Mortran pre-processor? In particular, Mortran3 on OS X.

I have found Mortran3 code at http://rcwww.kek.jp/research/egs/egs4_source.html. However, when I try to compile the file mortran3.f with the command: `gfortran -ff2c mortran3.f`, I receive the error

```
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.5.0'
ld: warning: object file (/var/folders/35/0vr6fpgs7k7bp94sk_syn2mc0000gn
/T//ccQDqd3K.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being 
linked (10.4)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_egs_fdate__", referenced from:
  _MAIN__ in ccQDqd3K.o
  _rw_ in ccQDqd3K.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Those first four lines are sort of business as usual, although perhaps they interfere with what pops up downstream?

Comment: Mortran is just a macro pre-processor that outputs Fortran code, so you can probably get your mortran processor to save the Fortran output without calling a Fortran compiler and you can just read that file.

Comment: But expect ugly code with gotos as a result. Reading the Mortran should be easier, with more powerful control structures (in comparison to FORTRAN IV).

Comment: @casey I don't know that I have a Mortran processor. I've obtained the EGS4 source code, which provides a Mortran3 processor; I'm currently fiddling with it to get the processor working.

Comment: The error message means the compile works! You just have a wrong symbol name for the fdate nonstandard intrinsic. Provide your own or dig inside the code find the reason for that.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FDATE.html We can't say more without the source code.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks Vladimir. You are right, the pre-processed code is hideous. I managed to find the glmnet.f code elsewhere, so I don't need to convert.