# How does `loop` with `if(test) next` work in Mortran?

Tags: loops, if-statement, fortran, logic

I have a Mortran code here.

```
loop<(do something)   
<k=1,n; if(test) next; 
(do another thing 1); (do another thing 2);
(do another thing 3);
>
>
```

What happens if the test statement is true?
I guess the code execute do another thing 2 jumping over do another thing 1.

The above code snippet is part of the `glmnet` package in R.
There is `.Fortran("lognet",~~)` in the package.

Comment: That isn't Fortran code you have.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code you found this in?

Comment: The link is https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/inst/mortran/glmnet5.m#L1563

Comment: The range of lines from the top is 1521~1534 I am asking.

Comment: Given the name in the link - expect that to be [Mortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33789412/3157076) code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortran

Comment: Thanks, mortran is an extension of the fortran so they share the same logic I guess. So... the above code without ; would compile in Fortran.!!
Would you explain a flow of the code in fortran?

Comment: It will NOT compile in Fortran. It is NOT Fortran. Mortran isn't Fortran. Mortran is a completely separate language that compiles to Fortran code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test` evaluates to `.true.` then then the program goes to the next iteration of this loop.  See this [Mortran User's Guide](http://rcwww.kek.jp/research/egs/epub/manuals/append4.html) for more details.